# Capitalize random letters of a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, random, replace

I want to capitalize random letters in a string and echo the complete sentence from **hello69.world** to **HeLlO69.WoRlD**. Each time the functions run, it should capitalize random letters and exclude special characters and digits. I've tried this so far but it only selects the first 5 characters in string every time and outputs only Capitalized letters. How to fix this?

```
<?php
 $string = "hellohg.09ui8vkosjbdh";

    $selchr = substr($string,0, 5);
    $caps = strtoupper($selchr);
    echo substr_replace($string, $caps,0);
?>
```

Comment: There's no actual attempt at randomness in your code... Is the number of characters to be uppercased also random?

Comment: It's also unclear if your input will always be completely lowercased or it might contain uppercase characters already and what should be done in that case.

Comment: @El_Vanja no, I will fix the number of characters to be capitalized and yes the input will always be lowercased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you want to CAPITALIZE 5 letters randomly:

```php
$string = "hellohg.09ui8vkosjbdh";
$characters = str_split($string);
$i = 0;
do{
    $random_index = rand(0, count($characters) - 1);
    $unique_indices[] = ""; //UNIQUE INDICES
    while (in_array($random_index, $unique_indices)) {
        $random_index = rand(0, count($characters) - 1);
    }
    $unique_indices[] = $random_index;

    $random_letter = $characters[$random_index];
    if(ctype_alpha($random_letter)){//only letters 
        $characters[$random_index] = strtoupper($random_letter);
        $i++;
    }
}while($i<5);echo implode('', $characters);
```

Thanks to @El_Vanja for Note `UNIQUE INDICES`

Comment: Note that this code might select the same character multiple times, resulting in less than five letters being uppercased.

Comment: How can "select the same character multiple times"!? I tested it,  works fine select five  characters *only letters* randomly and make them UPPERCASE!

Comment: Because `$random_index = rand(0, count($characters) - 1);` doesn't remember the previously generated values and may generate the same one, given enough runs. Here's a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/6PRKNuh9) of dumps I obtained by running your code a 100 times. You can see the effect on the third and fourth iteration already.

Comment: Now I get it why you said "select the same character multiple times"! Yes You're right and I update the answer!